Why won't Samba update past 4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu1.6 even though 4.20.5 is available?
I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS and using apt-get to update Samba. It keeps telling me
samba is already the newest version (2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu1.6)
But the Samba release site says there are many other newer versions.
Is there a reason I can't get the latest version? Do I need to install manually?

Ubuntu uses a stable release model, and you're using a rather old release of Ubuntu (22.04 or the 2022-April release; there were five newer releases since 22.04). The stable release model keeps the same software with backports of security fixes only; if you want newer software your approach is to release-upgrade. Your machine knows only of software in the repository its aware of (ie. 22.04 or jammy, which has security fixes only added to it).
